# Building wiki like functionality

Tags: codeigniter, wiki, document

I am building my application in Codeigniter. It has a module where users create documents, which can be edited at a later time. How do I implement a 'history' of revisions, perhaps like a wiki ? Is it possible to embed a php wiki in a web app (twiki/dokuwiki)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider embeding a wiki into your application so that you don't have to create your own wiki-like functionality from scratch.  I know [dooWikis](http://doowikis.com) enables you to do this without displaying any third-party branding or advertising on your site while still giving you control over who gets to make changes to the content.